# PS4 controller blinking white then goes orange

Tags: controllers, ps4

The other day my ps4 controller fell into some water. I drained it and dried it off best I could. However, it won't connect to my ps4. One time I did get it to connect for 5 seconds before it shut off saying that the battery was low.

Is my controller done for or do I just need to buy a better cable? I tried resetting it and everything.

Answer (score 1):

As with anything electronic, if it gets into water, you are probably going to have to invest in a new (electronic thing). There are occasions when this is not the case, but you'll usually have to do something like the following:

1. **Open the device and remove the water** somehow.  There are many different ways to remove water (paper / cloth towels, compressed air, blow drying [cool setting!], etc), but *all of these* have their drawbacks and *all of them* can cause *further damage* if not used cautiously. I want to repeat that: ***read up on how to best dry the thing that got wet!*** [There are websites that will show you how to safely open your controller.](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/DualShock_4)
2. If you can't get all the water, as you probably can't, usually the next step is to **wrap the device rather tightly in a cloth or paper towel and place it in a sealable plastic bag with a cup or more of rice** (unless you have moisture-removing compounds at hand). The rice will absorb the water, the plastic bag will make sure the rice only absorbs the water in the bag, and the towel will make sure the rice doesn't get in the device.  It is usually recommended to do this for *at least a day*, but longer is usually better.
3. If you are lucky, the battery isn't shot. But, as it sounds in your case, it is. You will probably need to **replace the battery**.
4. When all is dry, and a new battery is installed, *it still might not work*. A chip probably shorted, and there is nothing you can really do. Time to cut your losses and **buy a new controller**.